# Exchange 2007 - getting an item count from a specified date range

Tags: exchange-2007, mailbox, command, statistics

Using the command below in Exchange Management Shell, I am able to get a list of all mailboxes on our Exchange server, along with their display names, size, and item count:

```
Get-MailboxStatistics | Sort-Object TotalItemSize -Descending | ft DisplayName,TotalItemSize,ItemCount
```

What I want, however, is to limit these results to a specified date range - for example, I would like to be able to find out how many items in each mailbox were sent/received/created between 12/01/2012 and 06/01/2013.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a good way to do it from EMS/Powershell.  The cmdlets don't tend to let you go digging around in users' mailboxes all that much.

You might be able to get the information using the Exchange Web Services, or maybe even some clever usage of export-mailbox.